# git merge equivalent of git rebase --onto

Tags: git, git-merge, rebase, git-rebase, merge-conflict-resolution

I find myself running into a workflow where I do the following:

- Create a feature branch ("`foo`") off of our `develop` ("master") branch
- Work, work , work...
- Submit a pull request for `foo`
- While waiting for approval, start work on a related feature...:
- Create another feature branch ("`bar`") off of my previous `foo` branch
- ...because the work is so closely tied that I couldn't progress directly from `develop` + I can't wait for reviews -- they sometimes take over a week
- Submit a pull request for `bar`
- Get approval for `foo` and merge it into `develop`
- [we use squash-merges]
- People are reviewing `bar`, there are comments, maybe `bar` is even approved by now
- Now I rebase `bar` as follows:
- `git checkout bar`
- `git rebase --onto develop foo`
- `git push --force origin bar`
- Get approval for `bar` if not already approved by now, and merge it into `develop`

This works as expected, but it re-writes history, and is frowned upon because people have already been looking at `bar`, and there's no way to really know what I did when I force-pushed.

If I try to merge without rebasing, I get all kinds of merge conflicts.  It's like `develop` is trying to "undo" my changes in `bar`.

My question is:

Is there an equivalent `git merge` workflow to `git rebase --onto`??? Something like:

- `git checkout bar`
- `git merge ??? develop ??? foo`

Is there some trick like... maybe I merge `foo` back onto `bar`, or some trick with setting the upstream?  I'm fishing here...

Thanks!

EDIT: Another thing... even this process can be a PITA if I have multiple commits in `bar`.  I'll usually merge-in `foo` to `bar` at the end, so there's definitely no conflicts between them.  But there might be a conflict between an early commit in `bar` and the latest `foo`.  So I have to do a `git rebase -i bar` on `bar` and squash it down to one commit before I do the `git rebase --onto develop foo`... Not great for preserving history... because now I'm squashing out comment commits, and such. So sometimes I use another alternative:

- `git checkout bar`
- `git reset foo`
- `git add stuff`
- `git commit -m "One commit of foo-bar delta"`

Again, grimy -- all the comment commit history is lost...

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I went with...:

```
git merge -X ours develop
```

And then since git is sometimes not-so-smart about the options it gives when there's a merge conflict, I verified the result with:

```
diff <(git diff Foo origin/Bar) <(git diff develop Bar)
```

Luckily, I hadn't pruned (I rarely do).  If there's a better way, I'm still open to other answers - going to keep this unanswered for a bit.

It would be nice if there were a solution that preserved the history of `Bar`, did not show the commit history for `Foo` (like `git rebase --onto` does), and required no intervention on merging the individual commits in `Bar` as they're re-played onto `develop`... But the more I think about it, I'm not sure that's theoretically possible.  So I think I can live with having the extraneous commits in `Foo` shown in `Bar`'s history.  The above meets all the other requirements.

EDIT: Haven't had an opportunity to try it yet, but I think this is what `rerere` is for.

Comment: I think they both preserve the history of `Bar` -- I just checked my PR, and it looks like everything is there to me.  I hope I'm not missing something...?

Comment: I just tested it, you are correct, that should work.

Answer (score 2):

> This works as expected, but it re-writes history, and is frowned upon because people have already been looking at bar, and there's no way to really know what I did when I force-pushed.

GitHub would clearly mark the previous commits referenced in the PR page as obsolete, but you are correct: it is cumbersome to detect the changes you had to make during your rebase onto `develop` before force pushing `bar`.

I would consider and pushing it as "`bar2`", and make a new PR from `bar2`, with a reference to the original `bar` PR.
That would allow a reviewer to [compare those two PR branches](https://docs.github.com/en/github/committing-changes-to-your-project/comparing-commits#comparing-branches) and quickly determine if anything significant has changed between:

- the original `bar` PR, which was already approved
- the new `bar2` PR, which has to be rebased onto develop in order to facilitate its PR merge to develop.

Comment: I'd consider using that in an extreme scenario where the below `git merge -X ours develop` failed to work.  And I included a method to verify whether it works or not.  I've seen really really weird merge-conflict choices before, so it wouldn't surprise me if there are cases where a failure could actually happen...???  So +1 for a backup option, but I'm going with the `merge -X ours` option for now.